# ValueError: Missing column provided to 'parse_dates': 'CRASH_DATE, CRASH_TIME'

Tags: python, pandas

I made a streamlit app. It works fine when I run it locally.
But, after I push it to heroku, I got this value error on the parse_dates:

```
    ValueError: Missing column provided to 'parse_dates': 'CRASH_DATE, CRASH_TIME'
Traceback:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/streamlit/script_runner.py", line 324, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/app/app.py", line 35, in <module>
    data = load_data(100000)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/streamlit/caching.py", line 591, in wrapped_func
    return get_or_create_cached_value()
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/streamlit/caching.py", line 575, in get_or_create_cached_value
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/app/app.py", line 27, in load_data
    data = pd.read_csv(DATA_URL, nrows= rows, parse_dates=[['CRASH_DATE', 'CRASH_TIME']])
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 688, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 454, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 948, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1180, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 2068, in __init__
    self._validate_parse_dates_presence(self.names)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1546, in _validate_parse_dates_presence
    f"Missing column provided to 'parse_dates': '{missing_cols}'"
```

This is the code to read the csv:

```
DATA_URL = ("https://github.com/chairielazizi/streamlit-collision/blob/master/Motor_Vehicle_Collisions_-_Crashes.csv")
@st.cache(persist=True)
def load_data(rows):
    data = pd.read_csv(DATA_URL, nrows= rows, parse_dates=[['CRASH_DATE', 'CRASH_TIME']])
    # data.seek(0)
    data.dropna(subset =['LATITUDE', 'LONGITUDE'], inplace=True)
    lowercase = lambda x: str(x).lower()
    data.rename(lowercase,axis='columns',inplace=True)
    data.rename(columns={'crash_date_crash_time':'date/time'},inplace=True)
    return data

data = load_data(100000)
```

I tried changing the streamlit and pandas  version but still got error. Error only happen when I set the DATA_URL to the csv file store in GitHub, but it works fine if I set it to my local file.

The code and the csv file for the project is here:
https://github.com/chairielazizi/streamlit-collision

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reference a file on GitHub, you need to make sure you are accessing the "raw" version, not the version from the GitHub interface. Adding the `?raw=true` parameter to your url should work:

`https://github.com/chairielazizi/streamlit-collision/blob/master/Motor_Vehicle_Collisions_-_Crashes.csv?raw=true`

Comment: Yeah thankss it works! Thanks for giving me this new knowledge too.